# Generate 1's and 0's grid without consecutive

Tags: java

I would like to create a program that creates a grid of one and zeroes with no three consecutives (one or zero, both vertical and horizontal). The program should generate random arrangement of grid every time it is called. The program should generate equal amount of 1 and 0 per row and column (ex: 12x12 - 6 zeroes and 6 ones). I already prepared a two dimensional array of integer where zeroes and ones will be stored. I also prepared a random number generator. My problem is I do not know where start and how do I do this without consecutives?

Here is a sample program of what I did so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.util.*;

public class 
SampleGrid
{

    int noOfTiles = 0;
    int status [][] = new int [12][12];

    Container contentPane;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel ();
    JPanel pnlGrid = new JPanel ();
    JPanel pnlArray [][] = new JPanel [12][12];
    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel (new GridLayout (1, 2));
    JButton btnArray [][] = new JButton [12][12];
    JButton btnNewGame = new JButton ("New Game");
    JButton btnRestart = new JButton ("Restart");

    /**
        * Constructors
    */
    /* Default Constructors */
    public 
    SampleGrid () 
    {

    }

    public 
    SampleGrid (int noOfTiles) 
    {
        this.noOfTiles = noOfTiles;
        this.status = new int [noOfTiles][noOfTiles];

        this.pnlGrid.setLayout (new GridLayout (noOfTiles, noOfTiles));
        this.pnlArray = new JPanel [noOfTiles][noOfTiles];
        this.btnArray = new JButton [noOfTiles][noOfTiles];
    }

    public void 
    launchFrame () 
    {

        Random rand = new Random ();
        int oneCounter = 0;
        int zeroCounter = 0;
        int first = rand.nextInt (2 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        int even = rand.nextInt (2 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        int counter = 0;
        int pointer = 0;
        boolean isFirst = true;

        contentPane = frame.getContentPane ();

        for (int count = 0; count < noOfTiles; count++) {
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < noOfTiles; count2++) {

                int random = rand.nextInt (2 - 1 + 1) + 1;
                pointer = (count + 1) * (count2 + 2);

                pnlArray [count][count2] = new JPanel ();
                btnArray [count][count2] = new JButton ();

                pnlArray [count][count2].add (btnArray [count][count2]);
                pnlArray [count][count2].setBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));

                // Generate the first Row
                if (count != 0) {
                    isFirst = false;
                }

                try {
                    if (isFirst) {
                        if (random == 2) {
                            if (oneCounter != 3) {
                                if (count2 != 0 || count2 != 1) {
                                    if (status [count][count2 - 1] != 2 && status [count][count2 - 2] != 2) {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                        status [count][count2] = 1;
                                        oneCounter++;
                                    } else {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                        status [count][count2] = 0;
                                        zeroCounter++;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                    status [count][count2] = 1;
                                    oneCounter++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (count2 != 0 || count2 != 1) {
                                    if (status [count][count2 - 1] != 2 && status [count][count2 - 2] != 2) {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                        status [count][count2] = 0;
                                        zeroCounter++;
                                    } else {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                        status [count][count2] = 1;
                                        oneCounter++;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                    status [count][count2] = 0;
                                    zeroCounter++;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (zeroCounter != 3) {
                                if (count2 != 0 || count2 != 1) {
                                    if (status [count][count2 - 1] != 2 && status [count][count2 - 2] != 2) {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                        status [count][count2] = 0;
                                        zeroCounter++;
                                    } else {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                        status [count][count2] = 1;
                                        oneCounter++;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                    status [count][count2] = 0;
                                    zeroCounter++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (count2 != 0 || count2 != 1) {
                                    if (status [count][count2 - 1] != 2 && status [count][count2 - 2] != 2) {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                        status [count][count2] = 1;
                                        oneCounter++;
                                    } else {
                                        btnArray [count][count2].setText ("0");
                                        status [count][count2] = 0;
                                        zeroCounter++;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    btnArray [count][count2].setText ("1");
                                    status [count][count2] = 1;
                                    oneCounter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        isFirst = false;
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe) {
                    System.out.println (aiobe);
                }

                btnArray [count][count2].setOpaque(false);
                btnArray [count][count2].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                btnArray [count][count2].setBorderPainted(false);

                pnlGrid.add (pnlArray [count][count2]);
            }

            zeroCounter = 0;
            oneCounter = 0;
        }

        pnlButton.add (btnNewGame);
        pnlButton.add (btnRestart);

        pnlCenter.add (pnlGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        contentPane.add (pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add (pnlButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        if (noOfTiles == 6) {
            frame.setSize (500, 525);
        } else if (noOfTiles == 8) {
            frame.setSize (650, 650);
        } else {
            frame.setSize (975, 975);
        }
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        System.out.println ("Enter the number of Tiles (6 / 8 / 10): ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int N = scan.nextInt ();
        SampleGrid grid = new SampleGrid (N);
        grid.launchFrame ();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you turn off your computer, get a pencil and paper, and write down **in words** the steps that you need to take to solve the problem.

Comment: Tried earlier. But all the algorithms I did will yield an error to the grid. I tried checking the back, front, top, and bottom of the current cell of the grid if there are consecutive. But the program didn't yield the correct results for the problem.

Comment: You might want to start with a simpler version of the problem: generate a random grid of zeros and ones. Don't worry about the extra constraints just yet.

Comment: If you don't have a formula, this is not really a programming question. If you do, but your code is not working as expected, post what you have so far.

Comment: If you have tried something, you should post what you tried and what the error was when you ran it. We can help you solve the problem from there.

Comment: That's a rather strong condition, my feeling is that a greedy algorithm will not work. You may need to do some backtracking.

Comment: @Henry: I would try brute force first.  Generate a grid, see if it meets the conditions.  Rinse and repeat until you get a valid grid.  The one constraint that the OP didn't mention was run time.  :-)

Comment: Updated. I included a sample program of what I have so far. In a for loop. the program should generate a random number between 1 and 2. If the generated number is 1, it will set the button text to 0. Otherwise, 1. The program only generates the first row.

Comment: Hm, couldn't that be achieved with bit masks and XOR?

Comment: @BryanJames You can simplify your code tremendously by generating a random 0 or 1 immediately rather than generating a 1 or 2 and then subtracting one. This avoids having to add 1 just to adjust later with an if statement (or better yet, subtracting 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sub-optimal solution that uses backtracking when filling the grid so that both of your constraints are fulfilled: at most two consecutive cells should have the same value in both horizontal and vertical direction, and the number of 0's and 1's must be the same in every row and every column.

```java
/**
 * Creates a m * n-grid where each entry is either 0 or 1,
 * each row contains the same amount of 1's and 0's and where no
 * three consecutive cells in horizontal or vertical direction
 * contain the same entry.
 */
public int[][] makeGrid(int n, int m) {
    // since we want the same number of 1's and 0's per row and
    // per column, both n and m must be even numbers
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be an even number");
    }
    if (m % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("m must be an even number");
    }

    int[][] grid = new int[n][m];

    // initialize grid: cells that have not yet been assigned a
    // value shall be marked with -1
    for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            grid[x][y] = -1;
        }
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    int[][] colCounts = new int[n][2];
    int[][] rowCounts = new int[m][2];

    // we're filling the grid from top to bottom and from left to
    // right. Instead of using two ints (say, x and y), we
    // awkwardly use an int-array with two entries. The only
    // reason for that is hideous construction is so that we can
    // implement 'backtrack' as a separate method.
    int[] xy = new int[2];
    for (xy[1] = 0; xy[1] < m; xy[1]++) {
        for (xy[0] = 0; xy[0] < n; xy[0]++) {
            // if the grid cell we're currently looking at is
            // empty, we set it to either 1 or 0 at random, unless
            // we've already exhausted the maximum number of 1's
            // or 0's per row or column, in which case we have to
            // use whatever is the opposite value.
            if (grid[xy[0]][xy[1]] == -1) {
                int cell;
                if (rowCounts[xy[1]][0] == n / 2) {
                    if (colCounts[xy[0]][1] == n / 2) {
                        backtrack(xy, n, m);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        cell = 1;
                    }
                } else if (rowCounts[xy[1]][1] == n / 2) {
                    if (colCounts[xy[0]][0] == n / 2) {
                        backtrack(xy, n, m);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        cell = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    cell = random.nextInt(2);
                }

                // if the chosen value resulted in a constraint
                // violation, we cannot leave it. By decrementing
                // xy[0], we make sure that the inner for-loop above
                // will come back here again in the next
                // step. When it does, it will go into the 'else'
                // case below because grid[xy[0]][xy[1]] is now no longer
                // -1
                if (!setGrid(grid, xy[0], xy[1], cell, n, m, colCounts, rowCounts)) {
                    xy[0]--;
                }
            } else {
                // the grid value at (xy[0],xy[1]) was set before, but the
                // value then chosen apparently lead to a
                // constraint violation. Whatever value that was,
                // let's try the other value instead.
                if (!setGrid(grid, xy[0], xy[1], 1 - grid[xy[0]][xy[1]], n, m, colCounts, rowCounts)) {
                    // the other value did not work either, so we
                    // have to backtrack further to find a remedy.
                    // Undo the grid value and move back to
                    // previous grid position.
                    colCounts[xy[0]][grid[xy[0]][xy[1]]]--;
                    rowCounts[xy[1]][grid[xy[0]][xy[1]]]--;
                    grid[xy[0]][xy[1]] = -1;
                    backtrack(xy, n, m);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return grid;
}

protected boolean setGrid(int[][] grid, int x, int y, int cell, int n, int m, int[][] colCounts, int[][] rowCounts) {
    // if a grid value was already set before at (x,y) the
    // colCounts and rowCounts were changed accordingly, too. We
    // have to undo that change first.
    if (grid[x][y] != -1) {
        colCounts[x][grid[x][y]]--;
        rowCounts[y][grid[x][y]]--;
    }

    grid[x][y] = cell;

    // now, we can update the colCounts and rowCounts according to
    // the value we just set
    colCounts[x][cell]++;
    rowCounts[y][cell]++;

    // check whether no more than two cells in a row have the same
    // value
    if (x-2 >= 0) {
        if (grid[x-2][y] == cell &&
            grid[x-1][y] == cell) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check whether no more than two cells in a column have the
    // same value
    if (y-2 >= 0) {
        if (grid[x][y-2] == cell &&
            grid[x][y-1] == cell) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private void backtrack(int[] xy, int n, int m) {
    // move one column to the left, if possible, otherwise move
    // one row up
    if (xy[0] == 0) {
        if (xy[1] == 0) {
            // we cannot backtrack any further
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No solution possible for n=" + n + ", m=" + m);
        }
        // backtrack to the last column in the
        // previous row
        xy[0] = n - 2;
        xy[1]--;
    } else {
        // backtrack to the previous column
        xy[0] -= 2;
    }
}
```

Besides being close to unreadable due to the awful `xy` array used here, this solution also runs into problem when the random assignment of cell values makes a "bad" decision that only leads to problems much later. In such cases, it has to backtrack all the way to the where that problem was initially introduced. If you think of a 12x12 grid, where each cell is either 0 or 1, that creates a search space of 2^144 possible assignments. As you can imagine, it is intractable to do an exhaustive search on that space.

I'm posting this solution only reluctantly both because of the readability problem of the code as well as to the practicality considerations outlined above. You might still want to have a look, though, perhaps it inspires you (or others) to a superior solution.

Answer (score 0):

As one comment: nothing goes with some puzzling (on paper, in thought).

First do the pure data, without the GUI.

```
int[] generateLineHalf1sNo111(int n, Random rand) {
    int[] line = new int[n]; // All 0.
    int onesNeeded = n / 2;
    int consecutiveOnes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n && onesNeeded > 0; ++i) {

        // Because of past filling:
        boolean mustBe0 = consecutiveOnes == 2;

        // Because of following free space
        // To be at most filled two third: 110110
        boolean mustBe1 = n - i - onesNeeded / 3 < onesNeeded;

        assert !mustBe0 || !mustBe1;
        // Can always fill up with 011 011 011...

        int picked;
        if (mustBe0) {
            picked = 0;
        } else if (mustBe1) {
            picked = 1;
        } else  {
            picked = rand.nextInt(2);
        }
        if (picked == 0) {
            consecutiveOnes = 0;
        } else if (picked == 1) {
            ++consecutiveOnes;
            line[i] = 1;
            --onesNeeded;
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

`n - i - onesNeeded / 3` is the space available for ones.

Here the problem is that besides filling in random ones and zeroes, the *future* filling-in must be sufficient for a solution.

*By the way, I did not try it out.*